# Edit custom SF3 type inside itself

Tags: forms, symfony, types, attributes

I extended ChoiceType to create a RolesType, which goal is to provide a multiple selectable application-custom roles lists.

As my roles are defined in config.yml, I **don't want** to pass it for each RolesType usage, such as :

```
$builder
->add('authorizedRoles', RolesType::class, [
                'label' => static::ROOT_TRANSLATION_PATH . ".roles.label",
                'multiple'  => true,
                'expanded'  => false,
                'roles_list' => $roles,
                'attr' => [
                    'helper' => static::ROOT_TRANSLATION_PATH . ".roles.helper",
                ]
            ])
```

Instead, I tried to init this choice list by inject roles lists in RoleType constructor :

```
    public function __construct(array $rolesData) {
        $this->rolesData = $rolesData;

        foreach($this->rolesData as $roleId => $roleData) {
            $this->rolesList[$roleData['label']] = $roleData['key'];
        }
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->setAttribute('multiple', true);
        $builder->setAttribute('expanded', false);
        $builder->setAttribute('choices', $this->rolesList);

        $options['multiple'] = true;
        $options['expanded'] = false;
        $options['choices'] = $this->rolesList;

//        'multiple'  => true,
//        'expanded'  => false,
//        'choices'   => $this->rolesList,
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }
```

You can see my failed attemps **to act on the very form**. As I always want my roles, and I always want a multiple and expanded options to have the same values, it's far better (IMHO) to do it here.

So far, attributes and options leads failed. **How can I set this in the builder (or elsewhere in form type)?**

Comment: Have you registered you form type as a service (declaring suitable tag)? Do do you mean by *failed*? Any errors?

Comment: Yes, I correctly regsitered this form as service. I just accept your answer, I was totally missing the point about the configureOption goal in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `buildForm`, you can set choices in `configureOptions` as default values.

Try with this instead of `buildForm`, but keep your constructor:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(   
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => false,
        'choices' => $this->rolesList,
    ));
}
```

Remember to register you custom form type as a service with appropriate tag.

That could be something like:

```
services:
    app.form.type.roles:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\RolesType
        arguments:
            - '%rolesList%'
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

Actually there's a similar example in [Symfony's Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

The idea you presented has been deprecated, and removed in Symfony 3.

You can add a new option and pass the array of roles from Controller. This is how you add the option, in the RoleType class.

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefined(array('roles_list'));
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('roles_list', 'array');
    }
```

You say:

> options leads failed

Provide the error message if this would not work.

Comment: What exactly has been *deprecated and removed*? By the way, you cannot deprecate and remove something at the same time.

Comment: Not at the same time of course. I added the comma for the brevity thing. I mean creating a form using Controller's createForm() but by passing an instance of form type. In Symfony 3 it is only done using static class call.

Comment: You still can pass arguments to FormType's constructor, but you need to register it as a service with tag `form.type`. That's all.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that now. I always had dynamic values to deal with :)